# what's the best way to declare and get js object? (pattern)

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Javascript question.
About pattern or expression, could be duplicate question.

You can get a object using three of them below. 
result object works same.

Which pattern is the best when you use heavy javascript web application?

in order,
1. object literal case
2. closure case 
3. anonymouse function with new case

```
function car = {
  name: 'Q5',
  type:'SUV',
  wheels:4,
  door:2,
  score: 0,

  getWheel: function(){return this.wheels;},
  getDoor: function(){return this.door;}, 
  setScore: function(score){ this.score = score;}
}




var car = (function(){
  var name = 'Q5',
    type ='SUV',
    wheels = 4,
    door = 2,
    score = 0;

  return {
    getWheel: function(){return wheels},
    getDoor: function(){return door}, 
    setScore: function(_score){ score = _score;}
  }
})();



var car = new function(){
  var name = 'Q5',
    type ='SUV',
    wheels = 4,
    door = 2,
    score = 0;

  this.getWheel = function(){return wheels}
  this.getDoor = function(){return door} 
  this.setScore = function(_score){ score = _score;}    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no "best" way. There are a few OOP patterns in JavaScript, and the one you mentioned is one of them (and also a popular one). It is essentially a prototypical (or pseudo-classical) pattern with a closure to encapsulate private class-based static variables.

There are other patterns (e.g. the functional pattern recommended by Douglas Crockford).

I personally recommend the pseudo-classical pattern (although which pattern is best is a hot area of debate).

If you are doing OOP with JavaScript, I **strongly** recommend that you look into adopting a JavaScript library that has OOP built in, such as The [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) or the [Closure Library](http://code.google.com/closure/library/). Other libraries (e.g. jQuery, MOOtools, Ext etc.) all have OOP modules and/or plugins.

**Or**

While there are no classes in JavaScript, there are constructors and prototypes. These concepts come in handy when you have several objects that are similar (eg users contained in a userlist). Your code sample uses both of these concepts. Using names like myclass, it is hard to tell what you are trying to model. Here's an example of a User constructor and an extention to it's prototype:

```
var User = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
};

User.prototype.sayHello = function () {
    return "Hello, my name is " + this.name;
};
```